# C# Aspose Word Table : How to add Overline style to a Cell text

Tags: c#, .net, aspose, aspose.words, aspose-cells

I'm new to Aspose.Words for .Net specifically Tables, and working on recreating some documents for a customer  , and i want to create a table with severel  rows and columns dynamically,
my question is that how make the style Overline to a Text in cell (like the picture bellow : ex: cell in Yellow) ?
[image]

I searched too much in documentation but i found only the style for the pdf, i need it for Aspose Word ! can any one help me please !!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this by setting top border of the `Paragraph`. For example see the following code:

```cs
Document doc = new Document(@"C:\Temp\in.docx");

Table table = doc.FirstSection.Body.Tables[0];
foreach (Paragraph p in table.Rows[2].Cells[3].Paragraphs)
    p.ParagraphFormat.Borders.Top.LineWidth = 1;

doc.Save(@"C:\Temp\out.docx");
```

Comment: thank you soo much, your solution works very well except that it applies the style to all the cells of the table, to apply the style just for a particular cell you have to go through the run.    Ex :                                                                                                                                   
   foreach (Run run in cell.GetChildNodes(NodeType.Run, true))
            run.ParentParagraph.ParagraphFormat.Borders.Top.LineWidth = 1;